# What is the difference between an application and a command?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, path

What is the difference between an application and a command? e.g with respect to the `which` command.  Both are/contain executables.

Some executables in OSX are 'commands' designed to run from the command line (e.g. cat, less, python).  Other executables are contained within Application packages (Preview, Idle).  Is there any logical difference between the two?

**On the one hand**, the unix `which` command in OS X seems to think so:
When I use the `which` command in the OSX terminal I expected to be able to find my applications (for example) Preview.app.
but neither of the following return any results:
`$which Preview`
`$which Preview.app`

but
`$which python`
does return
`/usr/bin/python`

**But on the other hand**, this exclusion of apps and inclusion of commands seems arbitrary.  The results of running `Idle` (the app) and `python` are almost identical.

Is the distinction between an application and a command mere tradition ?  i.e. the /Applications folder traditionally has not been put into the `PATH` variable, but there's no reason why it couldn't be included?

Comment: `which` has nothing to do with application of the sort you're thinking of. I'm not sure where you got that impression. It's about commands and, yes, it relies on the `PATH`.

Comment: Ken I think that this is close: applications are not the same as commands.

Comment: What the difference between them is still escapes me.  Both are or contain executables, and both can perform simple tasks or more complicated ones, such as invoking an environment/interpreter.  Typing `python` at the command prompt leads to something very similar to running the Idle.app that comes with Python. This example seems to straddle both command and application.

Comment: You are not supposed to run most bundled apps from the command line. You *can* run them that way, but it can have bad side effects. For example, running the executable in an app always creates a new instance of the app. Not all apps cope with multiple instances running simultaneously. Also, very few apps are interactive at the command line, produce useful output to stdout, or take input via stdin. Are you perhaps looking for the [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command?

Comment: Putting `/Applications` in the `PATH` wouldn't help. The executable of an app bundle is buried inside, usually at `Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo`. Commands are searched for only **immediately** inside the directories listed in the `PATH`, not in their subdirectories. There are not usually any commands immediately inside `/Applications`.

Answer (score 1):

`which` tells you where the thing run by your command lives. If nothing is run by the command normally, `which` can't tell you about it - for example, when I type `Preview` into the command line nothing happens - which is why `which` returns nothing for it.

From the Man page for Which:

> The `which` utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file that would be run had these commands actually been invoked.

Comment: I think this is true, but it doesn't explain why.  Is it because the  Preview simply isn't in the path?  Or is it because it is an application, not a command?